# How to change the url of a template when i am sending a whatsapp message?

Tags: json, facebook, message, whatsapp

I am using the Facebook for developers API to send a WhatsApp message with a template and I need to change the URL in the template but it does not work.
This is my JSON:

```
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"recipient_type": "individual",
"type": "template",
"template": {
    "name": "*template-name",
    "language": {
        "code": "es"
    },
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image": {
                        "link": "*image"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "body",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "*message"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "button",
            "sub_type": "url",
            "index": "1",
            "parameters": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "*Text button"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"to": "*phone"
}
```

When I send the message it doesn't give any errors, however it doesn't make any changes to the template it sends to WhatsApp.

[image]

I hope you can help me with that.